# Django filter relation field set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have two models, here is simplified example of it:

```
class Application(TimestampedModel):
    ...
    forms = models.ManyToManyField(Form, related_name='applications', through='ApplicationForm', blank=True)


class ApplicationForm(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

I want to filter `forms` field on Application model. I try to do this:

```
queryset = Application.objects.get_active().filter(is_public=True, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
for application in queryset:
    forms = application.forms.filter(form_sections__form_fields__pk__in=application.public_form_fields.all())
    application.forms.set(forms)
```

But I get an error:

> AttributeError at /api/applications/public/79
>   Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use applications.ApplicationForm's Manager instead.

So my question is it possible, and if possible how can I do this?

Comment: you're using an intermediary model, you should [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). You can only use `set()` if you provide defaults for the extra fields (in your case `created_at`). Otherwise, you have to create the `ApplicationForm` objects yourself.

Comment: @dirkgroten But what should I do if I need only change forms field to the same forms but filtered?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an intermediary model, you should [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). You can only use `set()` if you provide defaults for the extra fields (in your case `created_at`). Otherwise, you have to create the `ApplicationForm` objects yourself.

So this would probably work in Django 2.2:

```
application.forms.set(forms, through_defaults={'created_at': timezone.now()})
```

In earlier versions of Django you have to go through the intermediate model:

```
application.forms.clear()  # remove all existing relations
for form in forms:
    ApplicationForm.objects.create(application=application, form=form, created_at=timezone.now())
```

Comment: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'through_defaults'

Comment: This attr works only for Django 2.2, but my Django version is 2.1